# Microsoft chart control - DataPoint is shown as PlottingArea

Tags: c#, charts, microsoft-chart-controls

I am trying to display a series containing several values.
I mouse hover a 'DataPoint' on chart to display a tooltip with some details.
But I am having a serious problem here.

[image]
[image]

The first value on chart is always detected as 'PlottingArea' So I am unable to display tooltip text for just the first dataPoint on chart.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Below is the event handler where I populate data on tooltip.
The last point when I watch the point in series it's 'Name' property is DataPoint.

But as soon as it gets drawn on chart it is being returned as 'PlottingArea'.

```
 private void chart1_GetToolTipText(object sender, ToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (e.HitTestResult.ChartElementType)
            {
                case ChartElementType.DataPoint:
```